# Any idea what set any of these are from? mostly minifigs and decorated bricks

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Just bought a random mixed box on Facebay, trying to work out what sets might be there. These are the most distinctive pieces.

[image: mostly minifigs and decorated bricks]

Answer (score 6):

I can identify:

- Several parts which appear together in [set 76170](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76170-1):

  - [sh612 "Iron Man with Silver Hexagon on Chest" minifigure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sh612)
  - [11092 "Hand, Gorilla Fist"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11092) (in pearl gold)
  - [73304 "Power Burst Figure Pedestal"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=73304), once in trans-clear blue and once in trans-orange.
- [6213p02 "Brick 2 x 6 x 3 with Green, Yellow and Blue Dots Pattern"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6213p02), which appears in 5 sets.
- [4215ap18 "Panel 1 x 4 x 3 - Solid Studs with Black 'POLICE' Bar and White Stripes Pattern"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4215ap18), which only appears in [set 6684](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6684-1).
- [cty0974 "Fire - Reflective Stripes, Bright Light Orange Suit, Life Jacket, Red Fire Helmet" minifigure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=cty0974), which appears in two sets (the torso and head appear in other combinations, though).
- [cty0179a "Sweater Cropped with Bow, Heart Necklace, Tan Legs, Reddish Brown Hair Female Ponytail, Black Eyebrows, Thin Grin" minifigure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=cty0179a), which only appears in [set 7937](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7937-1).
- [4491a "Horse saddle with one clip"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4491a) in yellow, which appears in 5 sets.
- [soc028 "Soccer Player - Green and White Team with Number 9 on Back" minifigure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=soc028). I'm assuming it's no# 9 because of the mustache, but I cannot be sure, specially since the pants are wrong. Anyway there's only one set with the "green and white team" striped torsos: [set 3409](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3409-1).
- An ubiquitous orange [96874 brick separator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=96874). As I'm writing this, it appears in a whopping 1016 sets, so it's pretty much impossible to know where yours came from.
- [973pb0906c01 "Torso Open Jacket Hoodie with 4 Buttons over Medium Blue Sweater Pattern / Orange Arms / Yellow Hands"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0906c01). Since I don't trust it has the right head or the right pants, I cannot narrow down the 18 sets that minifigure torso appears in.
- [973px52c01 "Torso Divers Submarine Logo Pattern / Black Arms / Yellow Hands"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973px52c01), appearing in four sets. Note that the attached head is from a clone brand.

Note that you've got some parts from clone brands - notably the "policeman in swimming shorts" minifigure, and the aforementioned head on the red "Divers" torso.

I have doubts about the worker in orange hard hat - the head might be from [soc151](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=soc151), or from a clone brand (I recall that particular face expression being common in clone brands), plus there are no [hard hats](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3833) in orange.

I also have doubts about the 1x8 bricks with "fire" sticker being from a clone brand.

Comment: The figure in the lower left corner has an obviously non-LEGO head, but its torso is [genuine](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973px52c01&idColor=5#T=C&C=5). The worker in the orange hat might have a [genuine head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bp05#T=C) too.

Comment: Good catch! I'll edit the answer.